# Could someone explain this partial sum expression to me?

Tags: matrices, summation

I found this in one of my programming exercises that asks for the sum of each column so that the result vector V of size *m* is defined like so:

[image]

What exactly is this telling me? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a $j$ between $0$ and $m$. Say $j=1$. Then the above sum means that

$V(1)=M(0,1)+M(1,1)+...M(n,1)$. Since $M$ is a matrix, and in your notation $M(a,b)$ means the element of the matrix $M$ in $ath$ row and $bth column$, the above sum is actually sum of the elements of the $jth$ column. Hope this helps.